# HTML Slideshow - Images not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, slideshow

My slideshow is not working (HTML, CSS, JS). This is how it looks my code right now:

**HTML**

`<div class="slideshow-container">`
`<div class="mySlides fade">`
`<div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>`

`<div class="text">Nuestra cafetería</div>`
`</div>`

```
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
            <img src="img\Mocha-Lounge.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">Nuestra cafetería</div>
            </div>
        
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
            <img src="img\mochagirl.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">Nuestra cafetería</div>    
            </div>

            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            </div>
            <br>

            <div style="text-align:center">
                <span class="dot"></span> 
                <span class="dot"></span> 
                <span class="dot"></span> 
            </div>`
```

**CSS**

`* {box-sizing: border-box}`

`.mySlides {`
`display:none;`
`}`

`img {vertical-align: middle;}`

`.slideshow-container {`
`max-width: 1000px;`
`position: relative;`
`margin: auto;`
`height: 300px;`
`margin-top: 10px;`

`}`

`.prev, .next {`
`cursor: pointer;`
`position: absolute;`
`top: 50%;`
`width: auto;`
`margin-top: -22px;`
`padding: 16px;`
`color: white;`
`font-weight: bold;`
`font-size: 18px;`
`transition: 0.6s ease;`
`border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;`
`user-select: none;`
`}`

`.next {`
`right: 0;`
`border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;`
`}`

`.prev:hover, .next:hover {`
`background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);`
`}`

`.text {`
`color: #f2f2f2;`
`font-size: 15px;`
`padding: 8px 12px;`
`position: absolute;`
`bottom: 8px;`
`width: 100%;`
`text-align: center;`
`}`

`.numbertext {`
`color: #f2f2f2;`
`font-size: 12px;`
`padding: 8px 12px;`
`position: absolute;`
`top: 0;`
`}`

`.dot {`
`height: 15px;`
`width: 15px;`
`margin: 0 2px;`
`background-color: #bbb;`
`border-radius: 50%;`
`display: inline-block;`
`transition: background-color 0.6s ease;`
`}`

`.active, .dot:hover {`
`background-color: #717171;`
`}`

`.fade {`
`animation-name: fade;`
`animation-duration: 1.5s;`
`}`

`@keyframes fade {`
`from {opacity: .4}`
`to {opacity: 1}`
`}`

`@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {`
`.prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}`
`}`

**JS**
`let slideIndex = 0;`
`showSlides();`

`function showSlides() {`
`let i;`
`let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");`
`for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {`
`slides[i].style.display = "none";`
`}`

`slideIndex++;`

`if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}`
`slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";`
`setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);`

I'm trying to make a slideshow

Comment: Please define "_is not working_".

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you are using backslash in the path instead "/"?

So in that case

img src="img/Mocha-Lounge.jpg" style="width:100%"